# Session timeout kills CSRF token, making subsequent remember-me workflow fail

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring 4 web application, based on Spring Security and Spring MVC. It includes CSRF protection, as well as the remember-me feature. Relevant parts of the configuration are included thereafter.

```
<sec:http auto-config="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <sec:form-login
        login-page="/public/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/public/login?error"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        username-parameter="userName"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <sec:logout
        logout-url="/logout"
        logout-success-url="/public/login?logout"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <sec:remember-me
        services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="***" />
    <sec:csrf />
</sec:http>

<bean id="securityService" class="custom UserDetailsService" />
<bean id="authenticationSuccessListener" class="custom ApplicationListener" />
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <property name="key" value="***" />
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="securityService" />
    <property name="tokenRepository" ref="custom PersistentTokenRepository" />
    <property name="parameter" value="rememberMe" />
</bean>
<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="targetUrl" />
</bean>
```

**Scenario**: a user opens a POST form and starts filling it, gets a phone call or whatever, the session times out, invalidating the CSRF token, the user submits his form, and gets an "access denied". I have been testing this scenario by manually removing the JSESSIONID cookie in the browser (leaving the SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE).

**Expectation**: when the session times out, the remember-me kicks in, authenticating the user, and the request is successfully processed.

**Questions**: given the nature of CSRF and remember-me, is my expectation reasonable, or is it fundamentally flawed? Would it make sense to roll out my own implementation of a CsrfTokenRepository, storing the token in the database rather than in the session? What are the generally accepted approaches for the aforementioned scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A remember me will let you skip the login procedure but for safe reason a CSRF token and session attribute have to be invalidated after the expire time.So my suggestion is to increare the expire time to a more fitting value.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is what I had done as a temporary solution, I guess I'll keep it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to warn the user that the session is about to expire.

If your system supports draft versions of entities, you could auto-save a draft right before session times out.

Then show a dialog indicating that session has timed out and that they will need to login again, or at least click refresh. For good security, you should redirect them to the login page.

```
<script>

/* where n is the number of seconds until session times out on server */

window.setTimeout(function(){

  autoSaveCurrentForm();
  showWarning();

}, n);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the problem is not so much losing inputted data (I have some autosave features for important forms), than having users select a "remember-me" and then be requested to log in here and there. It's simply not consistent for a user experience (I'll get tickets like "remember-me does not work"), but I'll live with it for now.